# Android ImageButton how to have a clickable area that is larger than the image itself?

Tags: android

I have a small Android ImageButton on a screen representing an icon.  The problem is that it is difficult to touch, and activate.  I don't want to increase the size of the image itself but I would like to expand the clickable region and make it larger, so if the user is close enough to the image it will activate the onClick event.  How can this be done without implementing onTouch events for the surrounding screen area?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could wrap your `ImageButton` in another `ViewGroup` and set padding on the `ViewGroup`. Then you would listen for clicks on the `ViewGroup`. Here's an example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_button"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" />

</FrameLayout>
```

You would then listen for clicks on `R.id.button_layout`, and your `ImageButton` should receive all the same states (pressed, clicked, etc.) as the parent layout.

Comment: I tried adding padding left of 20-50 dip but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Is the idea to just set padding="20dip" rather than paddingRight, paddingLeft etc?

Comment: This would be perhaps fastest technique if it worked, but I still have not been able to verify it.

Comment: just tried setting padding="20dip" and still seem to need to click on on icon itself to get an event.

Comment: On second thought, since you're using an `ImageButton`, setting the padding will make your button larger, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: If not clickable then I suppose the onClick handler would be set on the button_layout or still on hte ImageButton?

Comment: On `button_layout`. I noted this at the end of my answer.

Comment: thanks for detailing a solution. I think listening for clicks on a ViewGroup is not well known.  The padding definitely does affect the clickable area with ViewGroups

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation... I just placed the icon using a relative layout, and then placed a larger button directly over the top of it that used a drawable that is completely transparent in normal state, and adds translucent color for pressed/focused/etc.

Comment: how do you specify translucent color?

Comment: I drew the icons (the normal state being a blank square of no color or alpha, of course) and referenced all through a drawable xml, setting the button drawable to the xml. not only did I do this to make the button larger than the image, but it allowed me to use a static system image for a phone icon to keep things uniform on each separate device

Comment: see here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html

Comment: Did you place the Icon as as ImageView?

Comment: And did you dynamically set the Button position based on the location of the ImageView?

Comment: yes, and lined up both centers horizontal and vertical in a relative view (which in my case, was inside another relative view so I could set it all the way to the right)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how our layout is configured but one thing that comes to mind is to use a relative layout.  Create your icon with a large transparent background.  You will have to fiddle with the layout to get it positioned correctly, but the transparent area will also be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be setting `TouchDelegate` on the parent layout of your child view which you want to expand its clickable are.

Technically a `View` can delegate touch events in a defined bounds to some other view.
You need to create a `TouchDelegate` which receives two parameter: 
a) the `bounds` of touchable area you want to delegate to some other view 
b) the `view` you want to receive this touch events

```
TouchDelegate delegate = new TouchDelegate(bounds, view);
```

Then you can pass it to the parent view:

```
parent.setTouchDelegate(delegate);
```

Now your parent view will delegate touch events inside the defined `bounds` to the `child` you passed.




Here is a full example:

```
public class ExpandTouchableAreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  FrameLayout rootFrame;
  Button btnHello;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expand_touchable_area);
    rootFrame = findViewById(R.id.root_frame);
    btnHello = findViewById(R.id.btn_hello);
    btnHello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(ExpandTouchableAreaActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
    expandTouchableArea(rootFrame, btnHello);
  }

  public static void expandTouchableArea(final View parent, final View child) {
    child.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        int expansion = 100; // how much pixels you want to expand touchable are (on each side)
        Rect bounds = new Rect(left - expansion, top - expansion, right + expansion, bottom + expansion);
        TouchDelegate delegate = new TouchDelegate(bounds, child);
        parent.setTouchDelegate(delegate);
      }
    });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way:**

```
    <ImageButton
  ..
  android:padding="16dp"
  android:margin="-16dp"
  .. />
```